# SAAJ-Impl 2.0.0 not working with Jakarta (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, soap, saaj

When using

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.xml.soap</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
  <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

in my JDK11 Application i still get the following error when running my tests:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion    at
> com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseBinding(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:563)
> ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]   at
> com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:445)
> ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]   at
> com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:219)
> ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]   at
> com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:179)
> ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]   at
> com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:148)
> ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]   at
> com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:334)
> ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]   at
> com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:292)
> ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]   at
> com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:201)
> ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]   at
> com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:182)
> ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]   at
> com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:178)
> ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]   at
> com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:89)
> ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]   at
> javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:82)
> ~[jakarta.xml.ws-api-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3] ....

Do i have a depedency too much or am i missing something.
Because when using JDK8 everything works. When using version 1.5.3 of saaj everything works either.